# Open Batch Questions in a separate dialogue box.

Tags: batch-file, backup, robocopy

I'm trying to make a Back Up.bat file using the RoboCopy command and am having some issues.
What I need is to back up a folder on to an external hard drive, and back up the same folder on to my laptop. My only issue is that the drive letter for my Hard Drive changes sometimes, I would just go to disk management and have a permanent drive letter, but I plan on having the folder backed up to multiple devices and don't want to have to repeat this again and again.

What I've tried so far is:

```
@echo off
robocopy "C:\Users\Zac\Desktop\Downloading" "%~d0\Backup\File Backups" /E /XF
robocopy "%~d0\Backup\File Backups" "C:\Users\Zac\Desktop\Downloading" /E /XF
```

I've also tried swapping the "%~d0" for a variety of drive letters, but got no where.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way out is to make the drive letter permenent as shown in the [Link](http://www.howtogeek.com/96298/assign-a-static-drive-letter-to-a-usb-drive-in-windows-7/).

Answer (score 0):

you can look up the drive letter if you have the volume name:

```
set "drive=undefined"
for /f "tokens=2 delims=," %%i in ('wmic logicaldisk where (VolumeName ^= "ExternalDrive"^) get caption^,status /format:csv') do set drive=%%i
echo %drive%
```

where "ExternalDrive" is the volume name of your disk.

(Note: the property `status` is not used, it's just one of several ways to get rid of the ugly wmic line ending with the desired token `caption`)